# Select components form stream selector (Clearcase,Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

I want to know if I can select components from a stream selector in ClearCase?

Because I have job in Jenkins who use this stream selector but when he start the job he download all the components from the stream selector, but I just want 3 components from this stream selector who contains 6 components.

How would you load only those 3 components out of 6 in a Jenkins ClearCase job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Jenkins UCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) itself doesn't allow much control:

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/58001105/modules_smaller.png?version=2&modificationDate=1319721394000]

> In general build performance is also much better in snapshot views that are hosted by the clients native file system - once they are loaded.
>
> **You have a small handle of control of what load-rules are applied to the snapshot views; Either you load all the components or only the modifiable ones.**
>
> We us a separate view per job, per client, which allows us to reuse views in a context the only changes very little between builds. Thus you will find that once you have loaded the view the first time, the successive updates will be very fast, since deltas are guaranteed to be small.

If you are using the simpler [Jenkins ClearCase plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin), then you can specify the exact load rules you want:

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/2916537/base_configuration.png?version=1&modificationDate=1391964920000]

So I would recommend the second approach, in which you cal list the exact folders, corresponding to the root directories of the 3 components you want to load.

Comment: there is a way to copy an entire workspace from a job to a workspace of an other job?

Comment: @user3588684 not directly through the native Jenkins ClearCase plugin, since each Jenkins job manages its own workspace. You could add a build step which would do the copy, provided you know *where* to copy.